# Regular Expression not Working

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2012, infopath

I am receiving some strings in this format:

```
"tel:+441234567890;ext=7890"
```

To extract the different numbers, I usually use these regex patterns, which return the shown output:

**ParseTelephoneNumber**

```
public static string ParseTelephoneNumber(string rawInput)
{
    var temp = Regex.Replace(rawInput, ";.*", "");
    return Regex.Replace(temp, ".*:", "");
}
```

> +441234567890

**ParseExtension**

```
public static string ParseExtension(string rawInput)
{
    return Regex.Replace(rawInput, ".*=", "");
}
```

> 7890

---

This seems to work fine in both `Visual Studio 2012` and `Visual Studio 2015`.

However, if this code runs in `VS 2012` as part of the code for an `InfoPath 2013` form, I see these results:

`ParseExtension`

> tel:+441234567890

`ParseTelephoneNumber`

> +441234567890

What is the reason for this? Does `InfoPath` use a different engine for calculating regular expressions?

Comment: `Regex` is part of .NET. InfoPath doesn't change its behavior. Are you certain that what you see in the screen is what is passed to the method? Is the input string HTML encoded perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your original string immutable in `InfoPath` I assume not, that is why you are seeing this behavior,
 If not are you sure InfoPath is passing the string in the same format to your C# code
Else can you try something like below ?

```
public static Tuple<string, string> ParseTelephoneAndExtension(string rawInput)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(rawInput, @"tel:(\+\d+);ext=(\d+)");
    if (match.Success)
    {
        return new Tuple<string, string>(match.Groups[1].Value, match.Groups[2].Value);
    }
    return new Tuple<string, string>(null, null);
}
```

Also regex is not VS dependent, it is more of a .NET engine.
As long as you send the string in the same format, you should get the same output.

Answer (score 1):

If the format of your string is like that every time, then why use any sort of replacing, just capture the values using groups to get what you need.

```
public static string ParseTelephoneNumber(string rawInput)
{
    var pattern = "tel:(.*?);ext=\\d+";
    var match = Regex.Match(rawInput, pattern);
    return match.Groups[1].Value;
}

public static string ParseExtension(string rawInput)
{
    var pattern = "tel:.*?;ext=(\\d+)";
    var match = Regex.Match(rawInput, pattern);
    return match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```